# an unhandled exception has occurred xaml click here to reload

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, exception, designer

Visual Studio 2010, I was able to view xaml in designer. Now every xaml I click, it gives me the exception and there is no info about what causes the exception. I tried reboot my PC, the issue still occurrs. I feel I must miss something? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed visual studio service pack 1 and now the issue is resolved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Often when using custom complex styles I find the designer struggles to render the XAML regardless of the service pack. Something to keep in mind